# Question about adding variables into scale items including NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

First of all, let me say this community is very helpful. As for my questions:

I have some data with likert responses 1-4 with 8 as I don't know and 9 as `NA`.

I was able to replace my 8s and 9s with NAs using:

```
df %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(.x %in% c(8, 9), NA, .x))
```

and did that for each variable.

My problem now is that I have good looking data with `NA`s, but I am trying to convert groups of variables into continuous scale items. For instance, ir1, ir2, and ir3, have Likert responses 1-4 to add up to `ir_scale` ranging from 0 - 12. The issue is when I add them:

```
irscale <- df$ir1 + df$ir2 + df$ir3
```

Any row that had an `NA` returns `NA` for the sum. e.g. 1+3+`NA` = `NA` , I want it to return 4.

I can't turn `NA`s into 0 as I am going to use regressions later. Thoughts? Here is an example data set:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HwtjJ-nChRwVuVQhAYucB_JkUagVtByj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share data with `dput(head(my_data,15))`. Links may break in the future. 15 is a random choice.

Answer (score 1):

One option is `rowSums`, which can take care of the `NA` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
df %>%
      mutate(irscale = rowSums(.[paste0("ir", 1:3)], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
irscale <- rowSums(df[paste0("ir", 1:3)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` for this. `na.rm=T` is a common parameter for dealing with `NA`s

```
mtcars[ 3, 3] <- NA
mtcars$newvar <- rowSums( mtcars[ , 3:5], na.rm=T)
```